# Does Profile Views count my visits too?

Tags: support, profile-page, view-counter

It makes no sense of the profile views counter to count the number of visits the profile owner makes to his profile when logged in. So, I am just asking for a clarification: The number of profile views is increasing quite  quickly on my profile. So, I suspect that my visits are being counted. Is my feeling true or is just hypothetical?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12744) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12766).

Comment: @J.M. So, since I use my profile as the place to see how I got extra  rep and stuff, it is likely that the counter has counted, self views.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the reference. I understand the site better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you refresh your profile page, the number of visits will not be increased. This is a normal behavior of profile views in various scripts.

Comment: I'll choose this as the answer, as it points out one aspect of the question. But, however, I feel @J.M. has pointed out right references for me.